# Is there any way to disable some previous or specific dates in Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, calendar, xamarin.forms.shell

I have some problems with using Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar.
Is there any way to disable previous and some specific dates?
So I can make it not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About disabling some previous data for Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar, there is one property ,  **MinimumDate** property, you can set data.

```
 <controls:Calendar
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            MinimumDate="3/17/2020"
            Month="3"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Year="2020" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it in **DayTappedCommand** in that control.

Hope it helps.